# Se produjo com.sun.jdi.InvocationException al invocar el método

Tags: java, sql, java-ee

Estoy tratando de obtener `SQLException.getMessage()` o hacer `SQLExeption.toString()` pero me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Se produjo com.sun.jdi.InvocationException al invocar el método.
```

según he leído esto se produce porque internamente el hascode es nulo, pero revisándolo me doy cuenta de que no es nulo, me está devolviendo un número.
No sé qué otra cosa puede estar haciendo que no funcione.

```
catch(SQLException e){
     System.out.println(e.hasCode());
     System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

el hasCode que me devuelve es 1937535868 y el toString me devuele:

```
Se produjo com.sun.jdi.InvocationException al invocar el método
```

Comment: Hola , si puedes compartenos el codigo que estas utilizando.

Comment: Creo que sería mejor si pusieras todo el stacktrace. Adicional a ello, creo que lo que quieres es `System.out.println(e.getMessage())`. De todas formas, lo mínimo que deberías hacer con una excepción es loguear todo el stacktrace, lo cual lo logras con `e.printStackTrace(System.out)`

Answer (score 0):

Te contesto con la [documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()):

**hashCode**

```
public int hashCode()
```

> Returns a hash code value for the object. This method is supported for
>   the benefit of hash tables such as those provided by HashMap. The
>   general contract of hashCode is:
>
> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
>   execution of a Java application, the hashCode method **must
>   consistently return the same integer**, provided no information used
>   in equals comparisons on the object is modified. **This integer** need
>   not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another
>   execution of the same application. If two objects are equal according
>   to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each
>   of the two objects must produce the same integer result. It is not
>   required that if two objects are unequal according to the
>   equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on
>   each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.
>   However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct
>   integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of
>   hash tables. As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method
>   defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct
>   objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal
>   address of the object into an integer, but this implementation
>   technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)
>
> Returns: a hash code value for this object. See Also:

```
equals(java.lang.Object), System.identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)
```

Es decir, el hashCode() no devuelve nunca una cadena (string), sino un entero (integer), por eso está declarado como `public int`. Si de todos modos quieres tratarlo como una cadena, lo cual, creo, no tendría sentido, deberías parsearlo, como se hace cuando se quiere convertir un entero a cadena.